# Additional nested <router-view /> does not render view from child route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I setup a new Vue3 project with routing. Inside src I create a new directory "foo" with a `Index.vue`

```html
    <template>
      <div>
        <div>Foo</div>
        <router-view />
      </div>
    </template>
```

and a subdirectory "views" with a `Home.vue`

```html
    <template>
      <div>Bar</div>
    </template>
```

Inside the foo directory I also setup a `router.js` where I register all the views for that feature

```js
    import Index from "./Index.vue";
    import Home from "./views/Home.vue";
    
    const featureRoute = {
      path: "/foo",
      component: Index,
      children: [
        {
          path: "/",
          component: Home,
        },
      ],
    };
    
    export default router => {
      router.addRoute(featureRoute);
    };
```

Inside the main router file I change the code to

```js
    import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
    
    import registerFooRouter from "../foo/router";
    
    const routes = [
      {
        path: "/",
        redirect: "/foo",
      },
    ];
    
    const router = createRouter({
      history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
      routes,
    });
    
    registerFooRouter(router);
    
    export default router;
```

The `App.vue`:

```html
    <template>
      <router-view />
    </template>
```

**What I expect:**

When running the app I get redirected to `/foo`. It will render a `div` with the content "Foo" and below that is another `div` with the content "Bar"

**What happens:**

The redirection works fine. But unfortunately all I see is the `div` with the content "Foo". The second `div` with the content "Bar" is missing.

---

So it seems it is not able to render the `Home.vue` file.

Does someone know what's missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`path: "/",` inside children is interpreted as root path by Vue Router. If you want to render something "default" inside the "/foo" route, use empty string:

```js
const featureRoute = {
  path: "/foo",
  component: Index,
  children: [
    {
      path: "",
      component: Home,
    },
  ],
};
```

Check [last example](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html) in the docs